# Error while using Watershed tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, watershed

I was trying to create watershed from a DEM that used polylines. So I converted that to raster and the raster to TIN. I delineated the TIN to fill the gaps and then returned it to raster. Then I got the flow direction, flow accumulation and used the snap pour point. I used the flow direction and the snap pour point data to create a watershed and got the pictured watershed. I am relatively new to ArcGIS and can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
[image: watershed]

Comment: What is wrong with the watershed?

Comment: It comes out looking like the attached picture. As opposed to the sample picture of delineated watersheds on ESRI's site.